# is there a specific way to write xpaths into rapidminer for web crawling

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, web-crawler, rapidminer

I have tried so many options, over many days to try and extract data. I don't know where I am going wrong.
for example, I am on the website reviewcentre.com and am looking at car selling site reviews.
I am struggling badly to retrieve information, most of my xpaths appear incorrect.
Where can I best learn how to do this properly, I have spent days at this.

https://www.reviewcentre.com/car_dealers/we_buy_any_car_-_wwwwebuyanycarcom-review_14068020

I know how to copy xpaths, but when it comes to rapidminer, I can't extract the data.
I know I am doing it wrong, but I don't know what's right unfortunately.

examples include

```
//*[@id="ReviewTitle-14068020"]
h:html/h:head/h:title/text() 
this one works!
//*[@id="ReviewBox-14068020"]/div[1]/div[2]/p[2]/span
```

I have no problem it appears retrieving the xpath from the website, but using it for extracting data on rapidminer is not working at all..Would really appreciate if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you don't want to use **unique IDs** in your xpaths.

Make sure you have understood the concept of xml namespaces, too.